# Write unique dataframes to same sheet multiple times in existing workbook

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl

I have an excel workbook with sheets Sheet1, Sheet2 and Sheet3. I am trying to create a new sheet in the workbook (lets call it NewSheet) and write dataframes to NewSheet multiple times while also maintaining Sheet1, Sheet2 and Sheet3

For example I want to do

```
df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="NewSheet")
df2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="NewSheet", startrow=10)
```

Or in some cases

```
row=0
list_of_dfs=[df1,df2,df3]
for df in list_of_dfs:
     df.to_excel(writer,sheet_name="NewSheet",startrow=row
     row=row+len(df)+2
```

The problem is in `writer=pd.ExcelWriter(save_name, engine='openpyxl', mode='a', if_sheet_exists='replace')`

if `if_sheet_exists='replace'` then the only the last dataframe written to the sheet is saved and the others are lost because the entire sheet is replaced each time

if `if_sheet_exists='new'` then each dataframe is written to a new sheet and the result is a bunch of sheets named NewSheet1, NewSheet2, etc instead of all being written to the same sheet.

How can I write to the same sheet multiple times in an existing workbook?